# Skip Credit Card step - Magento 1.4.1 $0.00 dollar total checkout (due to discount code)

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

Is there a way to skip the credit card processing step in Magento 1.4.1?

I have a discount that will bring the total to $0 and can't figure out how to let the customer check out without having to input credit card.

Answer (score 1):

Enable the "Zero Subtotal Checkout" payment method. It will show only when the total is $0 and your customers can use that.